# Animation gets fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a script here that animate 3 divs containing product came from the database. It animate well when the page load in the first time but my problem is its not animate well after a min and everytime i refresh the page.

```
<html>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Slide2").hide();
    $("#Slide3").hide();
});
var h = 1;
var x = setTimeout(show2, 3000);

function show1()
{
    h = 1;
    $("#Slide1").show();
    $("#Slide2").hide();
    $("#Slide3").hide();
    $("#Slide1").css("left", "-400px");
    $("#Slide1").animate({left:'-1px'});
    clearTimeout(x);
    x = setTimeout(show2, 3000);
}
function show2()
{
    if(h <= 2)
    {
        h = 2;
        $("#Slide2").show();
        $("#Slide1").hide();
        $("#Slide3").hide();
        $("#Slide2").css("right", "-400px");
        $("#Slide2").animate({right:'-1px'});
        clearTimeout(x);
        x = setTimeout(show3, 3000);
    }
    else
    {
        h = 2;
        $("#Slide2").show();
        $("#Slide1").hide();
        $("#Slide3").hide();
        $("#Slide2").css("left", "-400px");
        $("#Slide2").animate({left:'-1px'});
        clearTimeout(x);
        x = setTimeout(show3, 3000);
    }
}
function show3()
{

    h = 3;
    $("#Slide3").show();
    $("#Slide2").hide();
    $("#Slide1").hide();
    $("#Slide3").css("right", "-400px");
    $("#Slide3").animate({right:'-1px'});
    clearTimeout(x);
    x = setTimeout(show1, 3000);
}

</script>
<style>
    #Slide1 , #Slide2, #Slide3
    {
        width:530px;
        height:100px;
        position:relative;
        background:blue;
    }
    #container
    {
        width:500px;
        margin:auto;
        border:1pt solid black;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:auto;
    }
</style>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <button onclick="check1()">1</button>
            <button onclick="check2()">2</button>
            <button onclick="check3()">3</button>
            <br></br>
            <div style='width:530px;margin:auto'>
            <div id='Slide1'>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:#ff0'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:#ff0'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:#ff0'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;background:#ff0'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='Slide2' >
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:green'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:green'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:green'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;background:green'></div>
            </div>
            <div id='Slide3' >
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:red'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:red'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;background:red'></div>
                <div style='width:120px;height:100px;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;background:red'></div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you have a lot of repeating code you don't need, those `check` and `show` functions could be cut down to just one each, where you pass in the required parameters

Comment: Is it just me or shouldn't you be using `setTimeout(...)` instead of `setInterval(...)`?  `setTimeout(...)` will rerun your functions if you would use `setTimeout(...)` will run only once and you would not need to use `clearInterval(...)`. Also it is wrong to have the code `$(document).ready(function(){` inside your functions it says that that part of the function should be run only after the pages' load event, remove that!

Comment: thanks men it work i used setTimeout but still i have problem when I'am trying to use the button(1,2,3) the animation gone wrong it became fast and when you are in the slide1 the slide2 will not animate, it will just show. @mortb

Answer (score 0):

You are not clearing your previous setInterval before starting new setInterval. Use clearInterval(x) before every setInterval in your show1(), show2() and show3() . hope it ll help.

You have redundant if else loop in your show2() . check it here (http://jsfiddle.net/cJ9FK/)

Hope it'll help, Thank you

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Actually i added clearinterval(x) but it just loop the function show2() I actually solve it using setTimeOut, but still i have problem with my button(1,2,3) when i click any of it, the animation goes wrong the button1 = check1()

Comment: Thanks men. I have 1 problem left because of my button(1,2,3) it has a onclick="show1()" but if I use it the animation goes wrong. the show2() just show the div and not animate it anymore